# Spring Cloud Data Flow- Task Execution fails with error ErrImgPull

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Added the Task Application using a Docker image by following the syntax : docker://*url_docker_img_for_task_app_from_private_repo*. This is successful.

Next, created a task and executed it. Looking at the logs for the App Pod created by SCDF, the application fails to pull the docker image and pod fails to access the docker image in private registry and ends up with the ErrImgPull status.

I have already created a Secret to access the private registry by following the steps here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_private_docker_registry.

Tried both : deployer. property way and global server level. Both failed to load the image.

Any clue how can I troubleshoot this issue ?

Comment: Check if the pod has the image pull secret set correctly. The property that you passed on should have it set at the pod level.

Comment: Thanks Gopinathan. I checked the pod properties and its not getting set. Not sure, what's wrong in my setup. Whas the application name here. I was using the name I gave on the SCDF dashboard while creating my App.  deployer.<application>.kubernetes.imagePullSecret=mysecret. Also, tried removing application name and have : deployer.kubernetes.imagePullSecret=mysecret

Comment: It is the application name when you register (in case the same application is used more than one time in the streaming pipeline then you need to use the label). If you are using the dashboard, you can set the deployment property when deploying the stream via UI. This way you can be sure that the name is set correctly.